# Complete list of causes of MaxRetryError

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, error-handling

I am currently using `from requests.packages.urllib3.util.retry import Retry` to retry some API calls, but I seem to keep encountering different errors as the cause to `ConnectionError` / `MaxRetryError`. As I currently catch then generate custom errors, I'd like to go through a complete list of causes that lead to `MaxRetryError`. I thought this'd be easy to find, but I can't seem to find it anywhere.

Does anyone have any reference to a complete list of possible causes that can lead to `ConnectionError` / `MaxRetryError`? The only reference I seem to be able to find is [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html). Seems like this is [an issue](https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/1198) others are facing too.

An example of what this error looks like is this:

```
ConnectionError(MaxRetryError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=8080): Max retries exceeded with url: ..... (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000026D26242688>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))"))
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Why isn't catching `MaxRetryError` sufficient for you?

Comment: I'm trying to route the inner exception beyond MaxRetryError and display a custom exception message. MaxRetryError is not descriptive enough to be routing this, which is why I need the cause of the MaxRetryError.